# subprocess AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_ouput' aix

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, aix

Not sure why im getting this error as subprocess check_output is in python 2.7 which im running?

```
ctmtest1-tctmsv80 [10] python del_jobs_main.py
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "del_jobs_main.py", line 51, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "del_jobs_main.py", line 42, in main
    p_call = do_sh_shell_command('env | grep machine')
  File "del_jobs_main.py", line 33, in do_sh_shell_command
    p = subprocess.check_ouput(string_command, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_ouput'
```

any help on this weird error would be greatly appreciated

Comment: it is a typo: ouput != output

Comment: how did i miss that...god your the man. thanks again J.F